# Loading multiple Profile based properties inside custom folder using Spring-Config Cloud Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am new to spring boot, have come across a situation...

l have 10 different property files based on various logical modules of a monolith application(db.properties,jms.properties, etc) and 7 envs(pre, sit1,sit2,uat1,uat2,prod, dr). The idea of having diffrent property files so that we can use them almost with no change whenever we move to microservice based approach.

One approach says - we use various spring application names
like - spring.application.name=db,jms,a,b .....

In this way we will land up having 10×7 = 70 files under same folde? (In order to make it profile driven) like jms.properties,jms-dev.properties,jms-uat.propetris...... for all various logical modules.

Is there any better approach to host the files using config server?

We have a monolith application and we plan to continue the same for the time being.

I am struggling to build such facility using spring cloud config server...if any one can help

Comment: I don’t really understand why you would split property types into different files based on what you typed. Why not place all types into one property file and then use spring’s built in functionality to select the correct property file to load based on profile, e.g. load application-pre.properties with spring.profiles.active=pre etc.

Comment: Hi Rob, yes that's the generic approach...yes can do it. But looking at the number of properties we use it will be a huge number. If we segragate the props, we will be one step ahead in the plan of making various microservices...

Comment: Hi Anirban, sorry I am still confused. How does separating your property files make any difference to your micro service design patterns?

Comment: Actually I was not aware of the concept of label. Trying to achieve it using the same. yes you are correct, it does not make any difference on the Micro Servi ce design patterns